# SQL Server : Graph-DB with soft delete isn't working as expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-graph

I try to use the graph functionality in SQL Server. Now I have a problem with soft-delete.

I have the following graph

```
[1] -> [2] -> [9 (deleted)] -> [4]
```

When I run the following script

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyNode 
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
) AS NODE;

CREATE TABLE MyEdge 
(
    State [int] NOT NULL
) AS EDGE;

INSERT INTO MyNode (Id, IsDeleted)
VALUES (1, 0), (2, 0), (4, 0), (9, 1);

INSERT INTO MyEdge
VALUES
( (SELECT $node_id FROM MyNode WHERE Id = 1), (SELECT $node_id FROM MyNode WHERE Id = 2), 1),
( (SELECT $node_id FROM MyNode WHERE Id = 2), (SELECT $node_id FROM MyNode WHERE Id = 9), 1),
( (SELECT $node_id FROM MyNode WHERE Id = 9), (SELECT $node_id FROM MyNode WHERE Id = 4), 1)
;

SELECT
    src.Id ID_SOURCE
,   LAST_VALUE(trgt.Id) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS ID_TARGET
,   STRING_AGG(trgt.Id, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS ID_CHAIN
--, STRING_AGG(compare.State, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS STATE_CHAIN
--, STRING_AGG(trgt.IsDeleted, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS DELETED_CHAIN
FROM
    MyNode AS src
,   (   SELECT
            *
        FROM
            MyEdge
        WHERE
            State = 1
    ) FOR PATH AS compare
,   (   SELECT
            *
        FROM
            MyNode
        WHERE
            IsDeleted = 0
    ) FOR PATH AS trgt
WHERE
    MATCH ( SHORTEST_PATH( src(-(compare)->trgt)+ ) )
    AND src.Id = 1;

SELECT
    src.Id AS SOURCE_ID
,   ed.State AS EDGE_STATE
,   trgt.Id AS TARGET_ID
FROM
    MyNode AS src
,   MyEdge AS ed
,   MyNode AS trgt
WHERE
    MATCH( src-(ed)->trgt )
    AND src.Id = 2;


DROP TABLE MyNode;
DROP TABLE MyEdge;
```

(Hint: this only works on SQL-Server 2019)

I get the following result

| ID_SOURCE | ID_TARGET | ID_CHAIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 2->4 |

There is no edge `2->4` but `2->9->4`. But the node 9 is deleted so it is used for the graph traversal but is suppressed in the output.

Is this a bug in SQL-Server or am I doing something wrong?

Or is there another way I should use soft delete with Graph-DB?

Comment: Cross-Post to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/42618907-graph-db-with-soft-delete-isn-t-working-as-expecte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter out the edges from/to soft-deleted nodes

```
....
(   
SELECT e.*
FROM MyEdge as e
WHERE
    e.State = 1
    and exists(select * from MyNode as x where x.IsDeleted = 0 and x.$node_id = e.$to_id)
    --and exists(select * from MyNode as x where x.IsDeleted = 0 and x.$node_id = e.$from_id)
) FOR PATH AS compare
....
```

Somehow the following query returns an error (after several secs of execution):

```
SELECT
    src.Id ID_SOURCE
,   LAST_VALUE(trgt.Id) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS ID_TARGET
,   STRING_AGG(trgt.Id, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS ID_CHAIN
--, STRING_AGG(compare.State, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS STATE_CHAIN
--, STRING_AGG(trgt.IsDeleted, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS DELETED_CHAIN
FROM
    MyNode AS src
,   
(   
SELECT e.*
FROM MyEdge as e
WHERE
    e.State = 1
    and exists(select * from MyNode as x where x.IsDeleted = 0 and x.$node_id = e.$to_id)
    --and exists(select * from MyNode as x where x.IsDeleted = 0 and x.$node_id = e.$from_id)
) FOR PATH AS compare

,   (   SELECT
            *
        FROM
            MyNode
        WHERE
            IsDeleted = 0
    ) FOR PATH AS trgt
WHERE
    MATCH ( SHORTEST_PATH( src(-(compare)->trgt)+ ) )
```

...and the error goes away by appending a condition/reference to src table, which is always true :

```
AND src.Id = src.Id --or src.IsDeleted = src.IsDeleted
```

There is definitely something going wrong [Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459)]..

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of filtering the edges.I will try if this solution is fast enough. If not I will add a `IsDeleted`-Flag to the edges and update them on delete and undelete.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating an isDeleted flag into the edge table, and updating that flag whenever a corresponding (to/from) node is marked as soft-deleted, and using isDeleted on the edge table subquery, is the preferred way. We do not recommend directly comparing $node_id to $from_id other than implicitly through the MATCH function.